# Combining Two SQL Result Sets by Single Column but want to show rows where no match

Tags: sql-server

So my first query is the following:

```
select Equipment_Reserved.idEquipment_Reserved,Equipment.Name,Equipment_Reserved.Reason, convert(varchar(20),Equipment_Reserved.ReservedStart,106) as [Start Date], convert(varchar(20),Equipment_Reserved.ReservedEnd,106) as [End Date]
from Equipment, Studies, Equipment_Reserved
where Studies.Study = 'MR18-42'
and Equipment.idEquipment = Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_idEquipment 
and Studies.idStudies = Equipment_Reserved.Studies_idStudies
and Equipment.Type = 'Reactor'
order by Name ASC, Reason DESC;
```

And results in the following:

```
idEquipment_Reserved    Name    Reason      Start Date  End Date
1                       813     Seed        10 Aug 2018 13 Aug 2018
4                       813     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018
2                       814     Seed        10 Aug 2018 13 Aug 2018
5                       814     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018
3                       815     Seed        10 Aug 2018 13 Aug 2018
6                       815     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018
7                       816     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018
8                       821     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018
9                       822     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018
10                      823     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018
11                      824     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018
```

The second query is the following:

```
select Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_Attached_To, Equipment.Family, Equipment.Name
from Equipment, Studies, Equipment_Reserved
where Studies.Study = 'MR18-42'
and Equipment.idEquipment = Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_idEquipment 
and Studies.idStudies = Equipment_Reserved.Studies_idStudies
and Equipment.Type = 'Raman'
order by Name ASC, Reason DESC
```

And results are the following:

```
Equipment_Attached_To   Family  Name
4                       Raman 3 Probe 1
8                       Raman 2 Probe 1
9                       Raman 2 Probe 2
5                       Raman 3 Probe 2
6                       Raman 3 Probe 3
10                      Raman 2 Probe 3
11                      Raman 2 Probe 4
7                       Raman 3 Probe 4
```

So, I can combine them in the following manner:

```
SELECT x.Name, x.Reason, x.[Start Date], x.[End Date], y.Family as [Raman], y.Name as [Probe]
FROM
(select Equipment_Reserved.idEquipment_Reserved,Equipment.Name,Equipment_Reserved.Reason, convert(varchar(20),Equipment_Reserved.ReservedStart,106) as [Start Date], convert(varchar(20),Equipment_Reserved.ReservedEnd,106) as [End Date]
from Equipment, Studies, Equipment_Reserved
where Studies.Study = 'MR18-42'
and Equipment.idEquipment = Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_idEquipment
and Studies.idStudies = Equipment_Reserved.Studies_idStudies
and Equipment.Type = 'Reactor') as x,
(select Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_Attached_To, Equipment.Family, Equipment.Name
    from Equipment, Studies, Equipment_Reserved
    where Studies.Study = 'MR18-42'
    and Equipment.idEquipment = Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_idEquipment
and Studies.idStudies = Equipment_Reserved.Studies_idStudies
and Equipment.Type = 'Raman') as y
WHERE x.idEquipment_Reserved = y.Equipment_Attached_To
```

And I get the following:

```
Name    Reason      Start Date  End Date    Raman   Probe
813     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 3 Probe 1
814     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 3 Probe 2
815     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 3 Probe 3
816     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 3 Probe 4
821     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 2 Probe 1
822     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 2 Probe 2
823     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 2 Probe 3
824     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 2 Probe 4
```

The problem is that I lost all rows where Reason = 'Seed' because those rows do not have any information in the second query.  Is there a way that I can change the combined Query so the results look like this:

```
Name    Reason      Start Date  End Date    Raman   Probe
813     Seed        14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 
813     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 3 Probe 1
814     Seed        14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 
814     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 3 Probe 2
815     Seed        14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 
815     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 3 Probe 3
816     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 3 Probe 4
821     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 2 Probe 1
822     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 2 Probe 2
823     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 2 Probe 3
824     Production  14 Aug 2018 31 Aug 2018 Raman 2 Probe 4
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using MS SQL server express, so 'sql-server'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want ALL rows from the `x` table regardless of a match on the `y` table, you'll have to use a `LEFT JOIN`.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT x.Name, x.Reason, x.[Start Date], x.[End Date], y.Family as [Raman], y.Name as [Probe]
FROM
(select Equipment_Reserved.idEquipment_Reserved,Equipment.Name,Equipment_Reserved.Reason, convert(varchar(20),Equipment_Reserved.ReservedStart,106) as [Start Date], convert(varchar(20),Equipment_Reserved.ReservedEnd,106) as [End Date]
from Equipment, Studies, Equipment_Reserved
where Studies.Study = 'MR18-42'
and Equipment.idEquipment = Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_idEquipment
and Studies.idStudies = Equipment_Reserved.Studies_idStudies
and Equipment.Type = 'Reactor') as x LEFT JOIN
(select Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_Attached_To, Equipment.Family, Equipment.Name
    from Equipment, Studies, Equipment_Reserved
    where Studies.Study = 'MR18-42'
    and Equipment.idEquipment = Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_idEquipment
and Studies.idStudies = Equipment_Reserved.Studies_idStudies
and Equipment.Type = 'Raman') as y
ON x.idEquipment_Reserved = y.Equipment_Attached_To
```